# Save CSV file in paperclip attachment (No handler found for <#CSV io_type:File io_path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a file created by CSV.open(..., "w", ...) that I've written data to, referenced by @summary_data, and now want to save as a paperclip attachment in my_model. What's the correct syntax, I tried:

```
my_model.update_attributes(summary_data:  @summary_data)
```

but it gives the error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError Exception: No handler found for <#CSV io_type:File io_path:"...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referencing the data written to the file rather than the file itself. You can always try the following:

`file = File.open('path/to/file')`

and then use:

`my_model.update_attributes(summary_data:  @summary_data)`

I am assuming here that summary data is what your attached file is called.